# SSIS SQL Server Execution plan based on local variable

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a query on SSIS that retrieves the data from the last N days from sql server

**WHERE Date > = DATEADD(dd,?,getdate())**

We have set a local parameter which is set to -45 days but the actual value that its being used its coming from a environment parameter which is set to -3.

During the execution its loading the last 3 days without any issue.

My question is when its creating the execution plan the database engine is using the local variable from the package (-45) or the global variable (-3) ?

Comment: I don't know enough to give an authoritative answer.  My belief is that the query gets passed by SSIS to the database engine with the appropriate parameter and then the execution plan is generated or reused from cache.

Comment: This query is stored in the SSIS package, or is in a stored procedure?

Comment: @TabAllemanThe query is stored in the SSIS package

Comment: When I am testing it on SSMS with -3 days it takes 7 seconds and its doing an index seek on the noncluster index. With -45 days  on SSMS again it takes 20 minutes and its doing a clustered index scan. Last night when the job was executed it took 20 minutes which means that it did a clustered index scan.I have changed the local variable in the package to -3 and I deployed. I will let you know the results tomorrow morning.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server is choosing an execution plan to run the query that SSIS has passed to it. The SQL Server has no awareness of variables/parameters/configurations in SSIS.